# Making a subimage have the same intensity representation

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, grayscale

I have two 16-bit grayscale images. One is a subimage of the bigger image. They are centred.
[bigger](http://tinypic.com/r/2n9hjd5/5) and the [smaller](http://tinypic.com/r/av3kih/5) notice, that the smaller looks slightly brighter.

When the two are displayed, the smaller looks brighter. Basically what I would like to do is them to keep the same grayscale value representation, i.e. I would like the smaller image have the same intensity appearance as the bigger one (since the GS intensity values in the respective pixels are the same). Any suggestions ?

```
for j in xrange(windows_a.shape[0]):
    print j

    pl.imshow(windows_a[j], interpolation='nearest') 
    pl.xticks(np.arange(0,window_size_1,1))
    pl.yticks(np.arange(0,window_size_1,1))
    pl.gray()
    pl.grid( color = 'y' ) 
    pl.savefig('./IW_small/IW_small_' + str("%05d" %i) + "_" + str("%05d" %j) + '.png')
    pl.close()   


    pl.imshow(windows_b[j], interpolation='nearest') 
    pl.xticks(np.arange(0,window_size_2,1))
    pl.yticks(np.arange(0,window_size_2,1))    
    pl.gray()
    pl.grid( color = 'y' ) 
    pl.savefig('./IW_big/IW_big_' + str("%05d" %i) + "_" + str("%05d" %j) + '.png') 
    pl.close()
```

Comment: Your images appear to be broken (at least I can't see them). Is it also possible for you to provide some minimal code describing how you created the plots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may set the intensity values yourself using the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments of the [`imshow` function](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

```
for j in xrange(windows_a.shape[0]):
    print j

    vmin, vmax = windows_b[j].min(), windows_b[j].max()

    pl.imshow(windows_a[j], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, interpolation='nearest') 
    pl.xticks(np.arange(0,window_size_1,1))
    pl.yticks(np.arange(0,window_size_1,1))
    pl.gray()
    pl.grid( color = 'y' ) 
    pl.savefig('./IW_small/IW_small_' + str("%05d" %i) + "_" + str("%05d" %j) + '.png')
    pl.close()   


    pl.imshow(windows_b[j], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, interpolation='nearest') 
    pl.xticks(np.arange(0,window_size_2,1))
    pl.yticks(np.arange(0,window_size_2,1))    
    pl.gray()
    pl.grid( color = 'y' ) 
    pl.savefig('./IW_big/IW_big_' + str("%05d" %i) + "_" + str("%05d" %j) + '.png') 
    pl.close()
```

Additionally, I would recommend to use the `interpolation='none'` argument, since that usually works better with vector graphics. This doesn't make a difference for you PNG file, though.

Comment: I am an idiot. Such a simple way to deal with this ! Thanks !